# C# "??" operator - what's wrong?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
// EWS Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder
private Folder _historyFolder;

_historyFolder = GetHistroyFolder(exchangeService) ?? CreateHistortFolder(exchangeService);

public Folder GetHistroyFolder(ExchangeService service)
{
    //if found the folder I want - return it , otherwise returns null
}

public Folder CreateHistortFolder(ExchangeService service)
{
    var folder = new Folder(service);
    folder.DisplayName = _historyFolderName;   // "who cares" :)
    folder.FolderClass = _historyFolderClass; // "IPF.Note"
    folder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot);
    return folder;
}
```

For some reason `_historyFolder` is always `null`, although `GetHistroyFolder(exchangeService)` does return a folder. Why is that?

**UPDATE I**

I have updated proof for the unbelievers !
If I separate it to 2 lines (without ??) it's OK!  but I still wanna understand why the first approach doesn't work...
why down vote? mean ppl..

[image]

**UPDATE II**

Thanks for the all warm people who down vote the question / vote for "close" this thread.

And Thanks for the true warm people who are trying ...

I used the workaround approach, split it to 2 lines

```
    _historyFolder = GetHistroyFolder(exchangeService);
    if (_historyFolder == null) _historyFolder = CreateHistortFolder(exchangeService);
```

you know what funny? Resharper suggests me to return it to how it was before...

Yea , this is a workaround and not real answer for WHY and WTF ... ( .net 4.5 )

**UPDATE III**

if GetHistroyFolder(..) is return null ( when foreach doesn't find ... ) , CreateHistoryFolder does return Folder object , and _historyFolder is getting the value

Comment: How do you test that it is null?

Comment: `_historyFolder` can only be null if both method calls return null. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: What happens if you separate the get into two lines as such: 
_historyFolder = GetHistoryFolder(exchangeService); _historyFolder = _historyFolder == null ? CreateHistoryFolder(exchangeService) : null;

Set some breakpoints and break it down.

Comment: Could you provide the code for GetHistoryFolder - you say that it does return a folder but haven't provided any code. If there is a problem it _may_ exist in there, but we won't know unless we can see the code.

Comment: @Marcus: Then it becomes null if GetHistoryFolder returns a folder.

Comment: *when* are you setting and reading that `_historyFolder` value? I'm guessing that you read it before it is set, or that the original value (or instance containing it) is lost by the time you read it. Did that folder get created?

Comment: Then I think you are doing something else wrong because that should not be possible.

Comment: because its "should not be possible" i posted it .. i'v UPDATED the post.. refresh the page to see the image ...

Comment: Just for the sake of being explicit, have you tried assigning `childFolder` to `_historyFolder` before returning from `GetHistoryFolder()`?

Comment: this is the first attemp to assign anything to _historyFolder .
if I do it without ?? , its ok , and get a the value from GetHistroyFolder()

Comment: No I mean explicitly assign it *within* the `GetHistoryFolder()` method. Something along the lines of `if (folder is what I want) { _historyFolder = childFolder; return childFolder; }`. Obviously it would then be better to make `GetHistoryFolder()` a void and possibly rename it to something like `AssignHistoryFolder()` but that's irrelevant to the problem.
I honestly believe this is because you aren't explicitly assigning to the `childFolder` to the `_historyFolder`.

Comment: Carl , I tried what you suggested , i changed GetHistroyFolder to void and assign _historyFolder within the method. It's a fix , but it's a workaround and not  answer for "why is this happening?"

Comment: Two guesses: 1. It's a problem with the debugger, maybe you're debugging release code and `_historyFolder` is optimized out. 2. you have an overload for `operator true(Folder)`.

Comment: Debug mode . There is no overload here. when the right condition of the ?? is taking place , it does get a value. I also played with optimized  ( on/off ) and same result

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a field why dont you use a property with a backing field. This doesn't exactly solve the problem but at least this makes it easier to debug.

```
Folder historyFolder 
{
    get{
        if(_historyFolder != null)
            return _historyFolder;
        _historyFolder = GetHistroyFolder(exchangeService); 
        if(_historyFolder == null)
            _historyFolder = CreateHistortFolder(exchangeService) 
        if(_historyFolder == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("history folder still null");
        return _historyFolder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for `_historyFolder` to be NULL, if `GetHistroyFolder()` is returning an object e.g.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        // EWS Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder
        private static object _historyFolder;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _historyFolder = GetHistroyFolder(null) ?? CreateHistortFolder(null);

            Console.WriteLine(_historyFolder == null);
        }

        public static object GetHistroyFolder(object service)
        {
            return new object();
            //if found the folder I want - return it , otherwise returns null
        }

        public static object CreateHistortFolder(object service)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I can only imagine that `_historyFolder` is being set to NULL after `GetHistroyFolder()` has been called. Your code looks incomplete, are you running in an ASP.NET or something?

EDIT:

In your code, where you call `FindFolders(new FolderView())` do this:

`FindFolders(new FolderView()).ToList()`

Because FindFolders returns an `IEnumerable`, I think you should call `ToList()` to ensure that all the folders are returned in one go, not just yielded.

Comment: console application , I have updated the post with image

Comment: Can you do what @Marcus suggested in the comments above? Split the call to `GetHistoryFolder()` and `CreateHistoryolder()` into two separate calls, see what each one returns.

Comment: I tried , If I separate the calls OR assign _historyFolder inside GetHistoryFolder() method , its working ..but ..it's a workaround ...

Comment: tried        foreach (Folder childFolder in rootfolder.FindFolders(new FolderView(numSubFoldersToView)).ToList()) and still same result

Comment: Hmmm, this is well weird. I've no idea why your code is not returning an object using `??`.

Answer (score 0):

may be "CreateHistoryFolder" return null

Comment: CreateHistoryFolder does not even being called , and it doesn't return null